# How to strip specific punctuation in a string using php?

Tags: php, sql, preg-replace

I am currently using this function to strip punctuation but it's like an uncontrolable axe murderer.

```
<?php $search = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/", " ", $search);?>
```

I want more control on what is been stripped. I would like to keep these characters and letters and numbers ofcourse

/  .  ,  :  -  ?

Thats all of them I think for now

EDIT:

This is the sql that query's the db

```
"SELECT c.ARTIST, c.TITLE, c.`CAT NO.`, c.FORMAT, c.`IMAGE PATH` FROM tracklisting t 
RIGHT JOIN catelogue c ON c.`CAT NO.` = t.`TRACKLISTING CAT NO.` 
WHERE t.`ARTIST` LIKE '%$search%' OR t.`TRACK TITLE` LIKE '%$search%'OR c.`ARTIST` LIKE '%$search%' OR c.`TITLE` LIKE '%$search%'"
```

EDIT:

Many Thanks To everyone, I have it working like a bomb now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply add those characters to your character class to avoid them being replaced:

```
preg_replace('#[^a-zA-Z 0-9/.,:?-]+#', " ", $search);
#                          ^^^^^^
```

A few characters will need to be escaped with a backslash inside the character class otherwise they have a special meaning: your chosen [regular expression delimiter](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php), a backslash, a close square bracket, and a hyphen (unless it's at the beginning or end of the character class). Also you will need to escape a quote so that it doesn't terminate the PHP string literal prematurely.

Comment: How do I escape the characters? Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: I need my search to find ac/dc. How do I put the / in because when i put it in, it pulls all my records out

Comment: @user1124199: Can you post the code you use to query the database?

Comment: @user1124199: Within the context of a regular expression, use a backslash `\\` to escape special characters in a character class.  Be careful if you're using a double-quoted string in PHP, as the escape character for that context is also a backslash, meaning you may have to double up your escaping in certain circumstances.

Comment: @user1124199: I updated my post to show how to include '/' in the regular expression by changing the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using regex, you could use something like this:

```
$symbols = array('/','\\','\'','"',',','<','>','?',';',':','[',']','{','}','|','=','+','-','_',')','(','*','&','^','%','$','#','@','!','~','`');

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($symbols); $i++) {
    $string = str_replace($symbols[$i],' ',$string);
}
```

It's a bit easier to understand if your not familiar with regex.

However, there are probably performance downsides doing it this way.

Comment: FYI: str_replace can take an array as the first parameter while keeping the second parameter a string, replacing all characters in the array with that string. Therefore you can remove the for loop and just use: $string = str_replace($symbols,' ',$string);